# sticky header in magento $j(window).scroll(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, scroll, header

Hello stackoverflowers,

I have the following problem with jquery :

I'm trying to include my already working sticky header: https://jsfiddle.net/6v6tx4xL/1/

in my magento store but it seems like the function:

Either `$j(window).scroll(function()` or

`if ($j(this).scrollTop() > 1)`

does not fire in magento.

I tested `$('header').addClass("sticky");` seperatly and it works.

P.S.: I'm already using `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

I'm running out of ideas why magento does not allow this.

Thanks in advance!
~Peer

Comment: user 'jQuery' instead of '$', eg: jQuery('header').addClass('sticky');

Comment: I don't think that jquery is having conflicts with prototype since $j is already working with other jquery scripts. As I said: $j('header').addClass("sticky"); is working

Comment: check console for any error

Comment: After alot of searching around, changing the $ to jQuery did it in one trick.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work there are two ways:

1st is if you call jQuery in the function:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function($) {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
                $('header').addClass("sticky");
            }
            else{
                $('header').removeClass("sticky");
            }
        });
```

2nd is you define the jquery no-conflict:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
                $('header').addClass("sticky");
            }
            else{
                $('header').removeClass("sticky");
            }
        });
```